# Add interactive points in a GLTF file

Tags: three.js, html5-canvas, blender, gltf

I have a GLTF file and I want to add interactive points over it with Blender if possible.

I start from an example code (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1TeMXIWRrqE) where I load a GTFL with three.js and render it into a canvas in HTML5. I need to add interaction sections like in this example:  https://skfb.ly/6GB8o

Comment: This question needs a whole lot more detail.  What sort of interaction do you want?  What is your target client device, API, platform, framework, and application?  Do you have a code sample you're working on, or will this fit into a preexisting app, and if so what app?  Please provide as much context as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Sketchfab has a [whole article](https://help.sketchfab.com/hc/en-us/articles/202512456-Annotations#:%7E:text=You%20can%20access%20annotation%20tools,end%20of%20any%20model%20URL.) on how to add the annotations seen in your example. You'll need to import/upload your glTF file to Sketchfab and then follow the steps in the article.